# After change Admin-PW I can't log in anymore

Tags: greeter, security

I changed the password in the admin functions, I restart the Laptop and when I want to log in
I write the password and enter → the display turns black for one second and the field for password is almost clear
When I make a wrong password the button shakes.

Best regards, Anne from germany

Comment: Did you set up any disk encryption?

Answer (score 1):

The screen shakes if the password is not O.k.

So it is almost sure that you don't type the good password. This might be a typo or you might not have the same keyboard setting (e.g., German vs. US English) in the Settings panel and in the Login screen.

Comment: Hello, make the steps with passwd {user_name} and set a new password. It didn´t work, when I write it in the box it shakes. The System said, that the new password is accepted

Comment: So there is another problem logging in. You might want to look at the  [questions](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=login+problem) with solutions.